# Execute prepared raw SQL in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a two table like this:

**table1:**

```
 user_id  |  fistname  |  lastname
 ----------------------------------
    1           Foo         Foob
    2           Bar         Barb
```

**table2:**

```
 user_id  |  date
 ---------------
    1         timestamp
    2         timestamp
    1         timestamp
    1         timestamp
    2         timestamp
```

I want to join `table1` and `table2` while `table2` is count of rows group by `user_id`, so the final result should be like this:

```
 user_id  |  fistname  |  lastname   |    hitcount
 -------------------------------------------------
    1           Foo         Foob            3
    2           Bar         Barb            2
```

Doing such thing in raw SQL is easy, but I don't know how is it possible to do it in Laravel.

I want use prepared SQL for security reasons.

Comment: Link - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

Comment: @Aparna There isn't any solution in Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can covert your raw SQL to Laravel code that is something like this:

```
DB::table('table1')
->join('table2', 'table1.user_id','=','table2.user_id')
->select('table1.user_id','table1.firstname', 'table1.lastname',DB::raw('count(table2.user_id) as hitcount')
->groupBy('table2.user_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the table relationships in your models.

What you explained is a `one to many` relationship.

Here You can read more about how to define the relationship and create the proper query using eloquent.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

```
Table1::Join('Table2', function ($join){
                $join->on('table1.user_id', '=', 'table2.user_id')
            })->groupBy('table2.user_id)  
              ->get([
                    'table1.user_id',
                    'table1.firstname',
                    'table1.lastname',
                ]);
```